# Ajax success handler - data is undefined

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Here is how I'm making an ajax request

```
  #action
  def get_item
    if request.get?
      binding.pry  #it always stop here, so it's working
      item = Item.where(...)
      unless item
        item = Item.new
        # .....
      end
      respond_to do |format| 
        format.json { render(json: item) } 
      end
    elsif request.post?
       # ......
    end
  end

  #view
     $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/contr/get_item",
                data: {key1: "value1"},
                //datatype: "json",
                success: function(data){
                  console.log("ajax success, data -> " + data[0]);
                    }
             });
```

Although the code within `get_item` is executed, the `data` value at the page is always `undefined`.

What did I miss?

p.s. Note that the request  **is being sent** back from server in json. I can see it in Chrome by "debug tool" by clicking F12 and going to Network tab.

Comment: Have you tried to see if `item` was defined when you hit the respond_to block?

Comment: use data.d if you didn't specify an object success: function(data){
                  console.log("ajax success, data -> " + data.d);
                    }

Comment: what do you mean by 'd'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 def get_item
   if request.get?
     item = Item.where(...)
     unless item
       item = Item.new
       # .....
     end
     render :json => item.to_json
   elsif request.post?
    #...
   end
 end
```

## view

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/contr/get_item",
            data: {key1: "value1"},
            //datatype: "json",
            success: function(data){
              console.log("ajax success, data -> " + data[0]);
                }
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your URL needs to tell what format you want to use. In your case it should end with `.json` to have a response in json.

```
#view
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/contr/get_item.json",
```